# Analytic formula for $E(\rho):=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \mu_m(\rho)/m!$, with $\mu_m(\rho) := \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\dfrac{\rho^k}{k+1}{m \choose k}{m-1\choose k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, random-matrices, catalan-numbers

Let $\rho \in (0,\infty)$ and for any integer $m \ge 1$, define $\mu_m \ge 0$ by
$$
\mu_m := \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{\rho^k}{k+1}{m \choose k}{m-1\choose k}.
$$

Finally define $E \ge 0$ by
$$
E := \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\mu_m}{m!}
$$

> **Question.** *Is there an analytic formula $E$ in terms of $\rho$ ?*

**Context:** $E$ corresponds to the expected value of the trace of the exponent of an $n \times d$ Wishart matrix, in the limit $n,d \to \infty$ with $n/d \to \rho$.

---

**Related:** https://mathoverflow.net/q/423906/78539

Comment: I note that this series evaluates to $E=e$ for $\rho=0$ and $E=e^2 I_2(2)$ for $\rho=1$ with ($I_2$ a Bessel function), in agreement with https://mathoverflow.net/a/423908/11260

Answer (score 1):

$$\mu_m(\rho) := \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\dfrac{\rho^k}{k+1}{m \choose k}{m-1\choose k}=\, _2F_1(1-m,-m;2;\rho)$$ where appears the Gaussian hypergeometric function.
$$E_n(\rho)=\sum _{m=0}^{n } \frac{\, _2F_1(1-m,-m;2;\rho )}{m!}=P_{n-1}(\rho)$$
I do not think that I could go much beyond except writing

$$E_\infty(\rho)=e \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n} {n!}\, \rho^n$$

where the first coefficients form the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{13}{24},\frac{73}{120},\frac{167}{240},\frac{4051
   }{5040},\frac{37633}{40320},\frac{43817}{40320},\frac{3582133632}{2827955323},\frac{5
   25382200}{355805701}\right\}$$

For $\rho=\frac 1 {10}$ this gives
$$\frac{4919476309996273890952908198463621}{4673674354662005734121472000000000}e=\color{red}{2.8612440756935690}0924$$ while the infinite summation gives $\color{red}{2.8612440756935690104}$.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting insight (upvoted);